# Sort the date column that is in different formats

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, office365, excel-2016

The date Column in my spreadsheet contains dates that are in three different formats:

1. `dd/mm/yyyy`
2. `dd/mm/yy`
3. `mm/dd/yy`

How could I get the dates into one format (I have 6k rows)?

Selecting: Column -> Format Cells -> custom -> `dd/mm/yyy` isn't working.

Comment: Sounds like some of your dates are actually text masquerading as dates

Comment: If you tap `ctrl+~` do you see a bunch of 5 digit numbers or a bunch of dates?

Comment: I pressed ctrl+~ and found both ->5 digit numbers,2 format dates(21/03/2015,19/3/15).

Comment: So that's your issue then.  These "dates" that are no numbers now are actually saved as text and not in a numeric date format. Therefore Excel doesn't recognize them as dates and cannot format them with a number format (because they are actually text). So you need to convert these dates into a number date format (would not be easy because letting Excel guess which date eg `03/02/2015` is may result in `2015-02-03` or `2015-03-02` you cannot know it just by looking at the date).

Comment: I recommend **always** to use the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date format `yyyy-mm-dd`, which is the only one that cannot be misinterpreted by humans.

Comment: do you need to be able to handle this dynamically or is this data fixed and this is could be a one time action? If it is fixed I'd give OpenRefine a try. This helped me out greatly in the past while fighting with dates and date formats in excel